# サーバー上のディレクトリが transmit で表示されない

Tags: ftp

いつもお世話になっています。
下記の質問についてご教示をお願いします。

---

### 【質問の主旨】

ファイル転送ツールであるTransmit5.6.1で/var/www/htmlの直下にあるディレクトリが表示されなくなりました。どうすれば表示されるようになるでしょうか？
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

### 【質問の補足】

#### 1.

ディレクトリが表示されなくなった理由はよく分かりません。ある日突然、/var/www/html直下のディレクトリが表示されなくなりました。

#### 2.

ターミナルを使ってサーバー内部にアクセスして、root権限に昇格して以下の動作を行いました。
するとターミナル上では/var/www/html直下のディレクトリが表示されます。

```
# cd /var/www/html
# ls -la

drw-r--r--  3 hoge fuga  110 11月 26 17:56 dir1
drw-r--r--  3 hoge fuga  110 11月 26 17:53 dir2
drw-r--r--  3 hoge fuga  110  9月 11 08:21 dir3
```

#### 3.

自分が使っているTransmit5.6.1では他のサーバーにアクセスできるように設定しています。
ですが質問をしたサーバーへはすべてドキュメントルートディレクトリ直下のディレクトリ、さらにその下で保存しているファイルまですべて表示されます。

---

以上、ご確認のほどよろしくお願い申し上げます。

Comment: Transmitでは(hoge)ユーザを利用してアクセスしていますか？また親ディレクトリである/var/ /var/www /var/www/html　それぞれの所有権と実行権限はどうなっていますか？

Comment: `/var/www/html`ディレクトリの実行権限(`x`)が外されているようですが、元からでしょうか? 付与すると解決しないでしょうか?

Comment: user20098さん。コメントありがとうございます。以下のコマンドを実行すると、html以下のディレクトリが表示されるようになりました。
```
# pwd
# cd /var/www
chmod -R 775 html
# ls -la
drwxrwxr-x  15 hoge fuga 4096 11月 25 18:14 html
```

Comment: keitaro_so さん。コメントありがとうございます。/var/www/htmlディレクトリの実行権限を`775`にするとhtml直下にあるディレクトリが表示されるようになりました。ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 1):

下記の手順で `/var/www/html` のアクセス権限を `755` に変更することで解決しました。

```
# cd /var/www
# chmod -R 775 html 
# ls -la
drwxrwxr-x 15 hoge fuga 4096 11月 25 18:14 html
```